# How i hide my page name in url with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

**My Code**

```
RewriteRule ^walls/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+) display.php?art_nm=$1 [NC,L]
```

What i get is:

> website.com/walls/i_love_coding

what i need is:

> website.com/i_love_coding

Comment: You can use  mod_rewrite

Comment: okae, can u plz write code according to my url above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). Basically, you give every request to your front controller which decide what to do.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then, use your "front controller" to forward request to correct script according to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

**index.php**

```
<?php

$name = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
$page = find_page_by_name($name);

if ($page) {
    require $page;
} else {
    require __DIR__.'/errors/404.php';
}
```

Be carrefully in the `find_page_by_name` function to not return the path of an unauthorized file; you should ensure your path is within a specific directory (see [realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)).

For example, an attacker could try to get http://example.com/../../etc/passwd !!!

For more complex routing, you should probably try a micro-framework like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) or [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/).